# What's the difference between 'accessories' and 'ornaments'?

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

Suppose a person is wearing earrings, and gold chains around the neck etc. for decoration of oneself. That could mean ornaments, I guess. However some understand it as accessories instead of ornaments but I could understand accessories as completely different meaning because accessory is something having a secondary function.

1. What's the difference between the two words *accessories* and *ornaments*?
2. In the sentence, "We must not take any of the ornaments inside," can we also use the word *accessories* instead of *ornaments*?

Comment: Have you checked dictionary definitions?

Comment: It really depends on what your sentence means by "ornaments". Can you give some context for it?

Comment: Suppose  a person is wearing ear rings, and gold chains around the neck etc..for decoration of oneself.that could mean ornaments, i guess. However some undertands it as accessoris instead of ornaments but i could understand  accessories as completely different meaning.because accessory is something having a secondry function.rite!

Comment: In that specific situation, I would almost invariably use the word 'jewelry' over either, but if I had to pick one, it would definitely be 'accessories'.  It's not uncommon to call jewelry 'accessories', but I've never heard jewelry referred to as 'ornaments' even though the function of jewelry is ornamental.

Comment: How does "taking ornaments inside" relate to someone wearing jewelry? I don't see the connection between your example and your second question.

Answer (score 1):

[Accessory](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/accessories): something added to something else to make it more useful, attractive, or effective

[Ornament](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/ornament): a small, fancy object that is put on something else to make it more attractive

These are the dictionary definitions of these words, so you can see the difference between them.  The challenge might come when you see, for example in a department store, a section called "Accessories" to refer to things like jewelry or handbags which (you might think) are much more *ornamental* than they are *useful*.

An *ornament* is, in general, functionally *useless*.  It just makes something look prettier.  At this time of year, for example, we put *ornaments* on a Christmas tree to make it look nice, but the ornaments serve no useful purpose.

Meanwhile, something like a travel *accessory* might be a spare cell phone battery, or a portable sewing kit -- something that has *some* useful purpose.  We would not usually say a "travel ornament".  That doesn't make much sense (except perhaps in a humorous or insulting way).

"We must not take any of the ornaments inside" is an odd sentence, and I think we need more context to judge if it is correct, and if "accessories" can be used in place of "ornaments".  Neither are usually the kind of thing you would keep outside in the first place.